# Python/Stripe invoice creation no line_item added

Tags: python, python-3.x, stripe-payments

In my python project i have to integrate with stripe API for automation my payements and invoices management.
I try to create an invoice like this one:

```
        stripe.Invoice.create(
            customer=c_stripe.id,
            billing='charge_automatically',
            tax_percent=22,
            charge=sc.id,
            description='Test ondemand invoice',
            lines=[s_li,]
        )
```

where c_stripe.id is the id of customer in stripe and sc.id is the id of the charge created previously.
Now i have to add line Items to my invoice and i do:

```
        s_li = stripe.line_item.create(
            amount=int(glob_amount*100),
            currency='eur',
            description='test monthly usage',
            type='invoiceitem'
        )
```

but system say to me that "there is no line_item method in stripe".
How can i create my invoice with different items line in stripe API?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for `stripe.InvoiceItem`. In particular, [`stripe.InvoiceItem.create()`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoiceitems/create?lang=python).

Here is an example:

```py
invoice_item = stripe.InvoiceItem.create(
    customer=c_stripe.id,
    amount=int(glob_amount*100),
    currency='eur',
    description='test monthly usage',
    invoice=invoice.id
)
```

You may provide `invoice.id` if you want to attach this item to a particular existing `Invoice`. If not provided, Stripe will attach it to the next scheduled `Invoice`:

> invoice optional
>
> The ID of an existing invoice to add this invoice item to. When left
>   blank, the invoice item will be added to the next upcoming scheduled
>   invoice. This is useful when adding invoice items in response to an
>   invoice.created webhook. You can only add invoice items to draft
>   invoices.

You may also want to check:

- the docs for correct usage of [`stripe.Invoice.create()`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/create?lang=python) (for example, there is no `lines` argument)
- [this example](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/one-off#creating-one-off-invoices-via-the-api) of setting up a one-off invoice
- [this explanation](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.stripe.com/forum/#!topic/api-discuss/tbNgmZH1LTY) of differences between line items and invoice items